# system calls detection and monitering

Tags: c++, monitoring, system-calls

I want to monitor a process's system calls but I am not sure how can I do this, I want to do this in Windows. any help would be great.I have tried doing this in Linux using signals but that was not helpful.

Comment: In Windows,  it's actually rather easy. Look up `CreateProcess` + `WaitForSingleObject`. .. You'll find other problems, but that should get you started.

Comment: Look up strace for Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shawn mentioned, strace is a great tool for monitoring system calls in linux. Here is one of those resources on strace that I like referring from time to time: http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2014-05-11/strace-wow-much-syscall.html